# Is Deploying A Mono Android App to Emulator Always Slow?

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I am building a simple mono android project and deploying to the emulator. Every time I try to run my program it takes at least 30 seconds to a minute to deploy and start the app in the emulator. Further, simple things like single stepping and inspecting variables take several seconds. Is this normal?

Also:

- Is it much faster deploying to an actual android device?
- Is it much faster using java instead of c#/mono android?
- If no, how does one efficiently program on the droid with such slow iterations?

My computer is no powerhouse but it isn't crap either: core 2 duo 2.6ghz, 4gb ram.

Comment: Yes, Android Emulator is slow.It is better if you test your app with real device.

Comment: FYI, I got my android phone. Deploying to an actual device takes fewer than five seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced with same problem too. But you can solved it in two ways (at least both these ways helped me):

1. Use MonoDroid on Mac. It **deploys** to emulator much faster.
2. Run your application in emulator with same Android version. I tried few different configuration and this one the fastest (as for me): application with android 2.1 and emulator with android version 2.1.1. For me it works pretty fast.

> Is it much faster using java instead
>   of c#/mono android?

I tried java and yes, it **deploys** (not works) faster.

Answer (score 1):

1) It is faster and more effective to test your program on an android device.

2) It isn't critical.

My hardware is like yours, I develop in Java, and have a wait time similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing android applictions using monodroid and deploy takes ~10s.

Just deploy without close emulator.

I was closing it all times and it take 30sec-1min to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

I did next and it helps a Little in speed:
MonoForAndroid 4.1 API level 16

1. Add to hardware 'accelerometer'
2. And set Device size Ram to 512 instead of 1024 (Will not start with accelerometer and ram 1024)

Emulator began work faster, not enough but it is better than nothing

Answer (score 0):

The same issue is without Mono too.

You can run emulator with parameters:

```
emulator @my_avd -no-boot-anim -qemu -icount auto
```

where `@my_avd` -- launch a virtual device named 'my_avd'

The full answer by @Timothy003 is here: [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator/6593004#6593004)

Works fine for me, deploying is much faster.